# What's the name of this UI pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, interaction-design, ui-patterns

Sometimes when some feature requires many different settings, they are written in a [cloze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloze_test)-like text, where the gaps (=variables) are displayed as comboboxes or hyperlinks which open some kind of lookup list.

Example:

> If the available space is less than [10%/5%/1MB/...] then [send e-mail to admin/play a sound/...]

The Outlook rules wizard is another good example of this.

What's the name of this UI pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From browsing existing patterns sites it seems this is maybe a mix of >1 pattern?

[Fill in the Blanks](http://ui-patterns.com/pattern/FillInTheBlanks) ([see also](http://www.designinginterfaces.com/Fill-in-the-Blanks))

[Input Prompt](http://ui-patterns.com/pattern/InputPrompt)

[Constraint Input](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=format)

Personally, I think you've maybe even hatched a pattern and should submit it somewhere... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a "Table Filter"

at least thats what we called it when I worked on a clone of that outlook rules wizard.

Comment: Quince defines Table Filter as something almost similar but not quite: http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search$text=filter/ViewPattern$pattern=Table+Filter

Answer (score 0):

'Rule editor', perhaps?  That's the OS X term, anyway.